# Zardaxt OS fingerprint scores

Tags: tcp, operating-system, fingerprint

I'm using Zardaxt (https://github.com/NikolaiT/zardaxt) to identify the OS of some TCP fingerprints I've collected. Zardaxt uses a scoring algorithm to return the best guess at the OS, the perfect score attainable in which is 20.5. I omitted some fields from Zardaxt database that are not present in my fingerprint so the perfect score in my scoring system is 16.5 The average best score my samples received was 6.65. How bad is this compared to 16.5? Does this mean that the OS identification of my fingerprints are unreliable, or is Zardaxt matching rarely exact and typically far off?

Attaching the Zardaxt scoring algorithm:
(dbList is the Zardaxt fingerprint database)

```
for entry in dbList:
        score = 0
        os_name = entry['os']
        if entry['ip_id'] == fp['ip_id']:
            score += 1.5
        if entry['ip_tos'] == fp['ip_tos']:
            score += 0.25
        if entry['ip_total_length'] == fp['ip_total_length']:
            score += 2.5
        if entry['ip_ttl'] == fp['ip_ttl']:
            score += 2
        if entry['tcp_off'] == fp['tcp_off']:
            score += 2.5
        if entry['tcp_timestamp_echo_reply'] == fp['tcp_timestamp_echo_reply']:
            score += 2
        if entry['tcp_window_scaling'] == fp['tcp_window_scaling']:
            score += 2
        if entry['tcp_window_size'] == fp['tcp_window_size']:
            score += 2
        if entry['tcp_flags'] == fp['tcp_flags']:
            score += 0.25
        if entry['tcp_mss'] == fp['tcp_mss']:
            score += 1.5
        if entry['tcp_options'] == fp['tcp_options']:
            score += 4
        elif entry['tcp_options_ordered'] == fp['tcp_options_ordered']:
            score += 2.5
        os_scores[os_name] += score

    avg_os_score = {}
    for os_name in os_scores:
        avg_os_score[os_name] = round(
            os_scores[os_name] / os_sample_count[os_name], 2)
```